# Is there a published example of booze made from goodberries?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Are there rules somewhere for making booze from the magical berries created by the spell [*goodberry*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsFtoG.html#goodberry)? Official material preferred but third-party material is acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Wizards of the Coast product for the [Eberron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberron) campaign setting [*Five Nations*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786936908) (July 2005) describes the magic item ***goodberry wine***, a partial description of which is below:

> A jug of the [goodberry] wine contains five doses, and each dose cures 8 points of damage as well as provides nourishment as if it was a normal meal for a Medium creature. An imbiber benefits from only one dose in a single 8-hour period; drinking additional doses of *goodberry wine* or eating additional goodberries during this time has no effect. (82)

Unlike many healing effects, *goodberry wine* works even in the [Mournland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khorvaire#Mournland). A clay jug of *goodberry wine* costs 250 gp and weighs 0.5 lbs. Creating goodberry wine requires the feat [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/featsAll.html#craft-wondrous-item) and the spell [*goodberry*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsFtoG.html#goodberry), of course.

The description lists no Fortitude saving throw for avoiding getting drunk off of it, but few alcoholic drinks from later texts reference the *Arms and Equipment Guide*'s rules for Alcohol and Intoxication (32).